# Why do I get two date/times in November when trying to populate a custom calendar in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I am tasked with creating a calendar. In my code, I have methods to get the current, next and previous months. In my method of setDates, you can see that I am getting the previous Sunday of the beginning the month to start the day of the week. Then, I am populating the calendar for 6 weeks (6 x 7) for a total of 42 days.

Whenever I go into the month of November for example, it shows two Nov 1st. When I consoled the array of days, i get this:

```
0: Sun Nov 01 2020 00:32:54 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time) {}
1: Sun Nov 01 2020 23:32:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
2: Mon Nov 02 2020 23:32:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
3: Tue Nov 03 2020 23:32:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
4: Wed Nov 04 2020 23:32:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
5: Thu Nov 05 2020 23:32:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
6: Fri Nov 06 2020 23:32:54 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time) {}
```

It looks like that is when Daylight Savings Time is. So on my calendar it is populating two days that show Nov 1st and then moves onto Nov 2nd which is not what I want. How do I fix that to account for daylight savings time? Do i need to create a method and somehow check to see if the date is daylight savings somehow?

My .html file

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class='table  table-striped table-narrow'>
            <tr class='month'>
               <td >
                <fa-icon style="padding-left: 30px;" [icon]="faAngleDoubleLeft"  class='month_prev'(click)="previousMonth()"></fa-icon>
               </td>
                <td>
                  {{ currMonth() }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <fa-icon style="padding-right: 30px;" [icon]="faAngleDoubleRight" class ='month_next'(click)="nextMonth()"></fa-icon>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <table class='table table-bordered table-fixed-header table-striped table-narrow'>
            <tr class='weekdays'>
                <td>
                  Sunday
                </td>
                <td>
                  Monday
                </td>
                <td>
                  Tuesday
                </td>
                <td>
                  Wednesday
                </td>
                <td>
                  Thursday
                </td>
                <td>
                  Friday
                </td>
                <td>
                  Saturday
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngFor="let w of allDates">
                <td class='days' (click)="showTimeEntries(d)" *ngFor="let d of w">
                    {{d.getDate()}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

.ts file

```
export class CalendarHoursComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  faAngleDoubleLeft=faAngleDoubleLeft;faAngleDoubleRight=faAngleDoubleRight; allDates = []; allMonths = [];
  resources: IResource[]=[]; resourceId: IResource = null;
  currentDate: Date = new Date();
  month = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

  constructor(private server: ServerService, private globals: GlobalsService, private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setDates();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    try { this.modalService.dismissAll(); } catch(err) { console.log(err); }
  }

 

  showTimeEntries(d: Date) {
      CalendarTimeEntriesComponent.show(this.modalService, this.globals.currentUser.id, d).then(r => {}).catch(r => {});
  }

  setDates() {
    let firstSunday = this.currentDate;
    while (firstSunday.getDate() != 1) {
      firstSunday = new Date(firstSunday.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    }
    while (firstSunday.getDay() != 0) {
      firstSunday = new Date(firstSunday.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    }
    let temp=[];
    for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
      let day = new Date(firstSunday.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * i);
      temp.push(day);
      if (temp.length%7==0)
      {
        this.allDates.push(temp);
        temp=[];
      }
    }
    console.log(this.allDates);
  }

  addMonths(date: Date, months: number) {
    let d = date.getDate();
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + months);
    if (date.getDate() != d) {
      date.setDate(0);
    }
    return date;
  }

  currMonth() {
    return this.month[this.currentDate.getMonth()];
  }

  nextMonth() {
    this.currentDate = this.addMonths(this.currentDate, 1);
    this.allDates = [];
    this.setDates();
  }

  previousMonth() {
    this.currentDate = this.addMonths(this.currentDate, -1);
    this.allDates = [];
    this.setDates();
  }

}
```

Comment: You could just use `firstSunday.setDate(firstSundary.getDate() - 1)` instead of using number of milliseconds. Then you don't have to worry about time changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well after further debugging and review, my code is actually working just quite fine. I did another console log and the two dates of Nov 1st are not there anymore and it populates the dates fine.

[image]

I worry though if it will mess with the times if i ever need to extract the hours. But I am setting this.currentDate to new Date() which does get the current time at any point in time.